# Powershell copying subfolders only

Tags: powershell

I'm needing to copy the subfolders to another location.

- Folder1
- -subfolder1
- -subfolder2
- Folder2

and need it like...

- Folder1
- -subfolder1
- -subfolder2

I've used this script ... 
Copy-Item -LiteralPath '\ipaddress\Exports' -Destination '\ipaddress\Exports2' -Recurse -Filter {PSIsContainer -eq $true}

I was hoping to get the subfolders but instead I get the main folder with subfolders underneath...

- Folder1

  - -subfolder1
  - -subfolder2
- Folder2

  - Folder1
  - -subfolder1
  - -subfolder2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to include *files* directly under Folder1:

```
Copy-Item .\Folder1\* -Recurse -Destination .\Folder2\
```

If not:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory .\Folder1\ | Copy-Item -Destination .\Folder2\ -Recurse
```